# StringFormat with Font Weight

Tags: wpf

I'm using StringFormat to show some bound data and works fine.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Name {0} | Id ({1})">
          <Binding Path="Name" />
          <Binding Path="Id"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I want the `Id` value (see XAML) to be bold. How to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx) (and/or [`Bold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.bold.aspx)) elements [inside the `TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) instead of it's `Text` property, you can bind and style them separately.

e.g.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Name "/><Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Run Text=" | "/>
    <Run Text="Id ("/><Run Text="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/><Run Text=")"/>
</TextBlock>
```

alternatively to `<Run Text="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/>`:

```
<Bold><Run Text="{Binding Id}"/></Bold>
```

Comment: Not clear enough for me :( can you please show me how in my posted XAML?

Answer (score 3):

try below one.

```
   <TextBlock Margin="12,0,355,13" Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Left">            
            <Run Text="Name "  />
            <Run Text="{Binding EmpName}"  TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Run Text=" | " />
            <Run Text="Id "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </TextBlock>
```