# WPF - StringFormat with weighted text

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I have a Question concerning WPF `stringformat`.

I want to bind a string to a `TextBlock` with a `stringformat`, currently I have something similar to the following:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding StringFormat="{}Text: {0}" Path="text"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

What I want to do is format the string to look as follows: 
**Text:** text

Or in other words, I wish to Bold the first portion of the resulting string. In my research for a resolution to the problem I found a similar question, [StringFormat with Font Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019664/stringformat-with-font-weight). However, I'm not happy with that approach, and most suggestions echo this solution to my problem.

I would like to know if this is the only way to do this. I'm not quite happy with that solution as I feel it bloats the XML and makes it harder to read.

granted I am new to WPF overall so if this is the acceptable way I'll do so.... I just want to know if this is the best way to aproach this simple problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only have one word for you: [Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold"
         Text="Text: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding text}" />
</TextBlock>
```

---

I should read the question entirely before answering; then again, you should not just link another page without adding details from it!

From the top of my head, there are only 2 solutions to have some markup formatting, `<Run>` and `<Span>`.

`<Span>` has some useful shorthands for `<Bold>`, `<Italic>` and `<Underline>`, but these do not support binding.
`<Run>` is verbose heavy, but supports binding.

In your case, the 'best' solution would be something like:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Bold>Text: </Bold><Run Text="{Binding text}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

For the side note, `Span` is like `Run`, but can contains other elements (Run, Span, text).

*For more details, [see also](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/).*

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the best way/only way to approach this? As I stated in my initial question... I'm not happy with this solution. Why is it the best? are there other methods? If so, what are the drawbacks to them vs. the `Run` solution?

Comment: Well, as I've been looking into it... any  other solution is far more confusing and complicated... As such, this is the most elegant solution and will be marked as such for this question.

Comment: @NealByington Edited the answer